# Get all items with different values

Tags: mysql

I have the following columns and entries:

```
TitleID    Entry
1           qedf
1           qwer
2           asdf
2           asdf
```

I want to get all TitleIDs that have a conflicting Entry. For example, something like:

```
SELECT title_id FROM table WHERE entry1 != entry2
```

The result should be:

```
TitleID
1 # because 1 has two conflicting values, 'qedf' and 'qwer'
```

How would I do this query?

Comment: Don't you mean "the same values"? That's what conflicting is, isn't it? But the title says _different_ values. Very confusing.

Comment: No, please see updated question.

Comment: Oooooh, that's a much more interesting question! With a lot of bad answers.

Comment: A few of those answers: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43784/4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `group by` and just compare the minimum and maximum values:

```
SELECT title_id
FROM table
GROUP BY title_id
HAVING MIN(entry) <> MAX(entry);
```

If you want the number of different entries, then throw a `count(distinct entry)` in the `select` clause.

Comment: can you explain me what does `GROUP BY table` mean ?

Comment: It means `group by title_id`.  That was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a group by and check the having clause:

`SELECT title_id FROM table WHERE entry IN (SELECT entry FROM table GROUP BY entry HAVING COUNT(entry) > 1)`

UPDATED PROBLEM (using self-join)
`SELECT title_id FROM table t1 WHERE (SELECT * from table t2 WHERE t1.entry != t2.entry AND t1.title_id = t2.title_id)`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you could also put `SELECT title_id, COUNT(entry) AS c`...`HAVING c > 1` so that you can reference the count if needed.

Comment: You can but he specified he only wanted the title_id's

Comment: Count is the number of entries that are the same (from the group by) having count > 1 means all those that aren't unique

Comment: @MauricioTrajano what if you have (1, asdf) and (2, asdf) you would get 1 and 2 in your result?

Comment: That's a good point, from his post it looked like entry and title_id where directly related, I will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `JOIN`, and `DISTINCT` removes the duplicates:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.TitleID FROM table t1
JOIN table t2
ON t2.TitleID = t1.TitleID AND t2.Entry != t1.Entry
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   title_id,
   GROUP_CONCAT(distinct Entry)
FROM table WHERE 1
GROUP BY title_id
HAVING COUNT(distinct Entry)>1
```

`GROUP BY title_id` splits the table into groups of different title_id

`COUNT(distinct Entry)` counts unique Entries within a group

`GROUP_CONCAT(distinct Entry)` Since you can't get an array out of MySQL, to list all these Entries you need to concat them into one string.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * From (Select TitleID,Count(distinct Entry) as CT From [Table] group by TitleID) a
where a.CT > 1
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @PeterHorvath Can you clarify why this does not answer the question? It is a sub query that retrieves the distinct Entry count and if the distinct count is more than one then it simply will return that ID as he is asking in his question.